# Properties of the relation $(x,y) \in R$ if $| x-y | = 2 $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Is the following relation reflexive, symmetric, transitive, anti-symmetric and/or partial order :

$$(x,y) \in R \text{ if }| x-y | = 2 $$

I think it's reflexive, I don't understand how to find for the other ones.

Comment: Do you really think that $|x-x|=2$ is true?

Comment: Oh! I was doing it with a wrong x,y input ( something like |4-2| for x,y.
So for reflexive you only take x value?

Comment: See the definition of "reflexive"...

Comment: symmetric:  if $xRy \Rightarrow yRx$

Comment: What definitions of *reflexive*, *symmetric*, *transitive*, and *partial order* have you been given?  Particularly, please look at *reflexive* again.

Comment: So if $|x-y|=2$ is $|y-x|=2$??

Comment: @Hugo , isn't the answer yes? Since it is a mod function and let's say i take x = 4 and y = 2

Comment: But since xRy => yRx i guess you cannot take two different values

Comment: @luke well it depends. I guess your talking about absolute values of reals or integers then yes it should be symmetric.  .  it is not obvious what x,y  are elements of. If $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|.|$ is the absolute value then it should be symmetric. You might want to edit the question to include definition of transitive, partial order,anti-symmetric for yourself

Comment: @luke For symmetry you need $\lvert y-x\rvert=2$ to be true for *any* values of $(x,y)$ that make $\rvert x-y\lvert=2$ true.

Comment: @GrahamKemp So if x = 4, y = 2. The following relation is symmetric!!

Comment: You need to be able to assert that $y\operatorname R x$ holds for *any* $(x,y)$ where $x\operatorname Ry$ holds, not just for some particular example. @luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relationship $R$ is *reflexive* if, for all $x$, it's true that $x R x$.

$$\textsf{Is }\lvert x-x\rvert = 2 \textsf{ universally true?}$$

> Clearly no.

---

A relationship $R$ is *reflexive* if, for all $x,y$, it's true that $x R y\to y R x$

$$\textsf{Is }\lvert y-x\rvert = 2 \textsf{ true whenever }\lvert x-y\rvert = 2\textsf{ is true?}$$

> Obviously, yes.

---

A relationship $R$ is *transitive* if, for all $x,y,z$, it's true that $(x R y\wedge y R z)\to x R z$

$$\textsf{Is }\lvert x-z\rvert = 2 \textsf{ true whenever }\lvert x-y\rvert = 2\textsf{ and }\lvert y-z\rvert = 2\textsf{ are both true?}$$

> Not telling.  Is it?

A relationship $R$ is *antisymmetric* if, for all $x,y$, it's true that $(x R y\wedge y R x)\to x = y$

$$\textsf{Is }x=y \textsf{ true whenever }\lvert x-y\rvert = 2\textsf{ and }\lvert y-x\rvert = 2\textsf{ are both true?}$$

> Not telling.  Is it?

---

The way to falsify each of these claims is to find a counterexample.   Only by verifying a counterexample is not possible can you state that a claim is true.

---

A relationship $R$ is a *partial order* relation if it is *reflexive*, *antisymetric*, and *transitive* .

> ...